# How to make two tableview cell in one controller class in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am making two tableview cell in one controller class on vertical style. I have different value both the cell. Left cell have some name value for eg(name :pradeep),and right side cell have some price value so if select on left cell on 3row and right side cell on 2 row so this two cell value I have to pass for open url.

Please help on this how to know which cell index are selected from both the tableview cell and what the value on that selected cell.

Comment: Oh my. You may want to consider rewriting this. I understand the geist of your question. You want to look at tagging objects so that you can react differently to their independent operation. This is *not* good UI practice. I'd recommend using a `UINavigationController` to display the options on independent views.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly then you should probably be using a UIPickerView:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnxS35JDqok

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html

Comment: no ur ans is not correct but friend thank for helping to me i get the solution it small mistake it working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple tableview cell. You need to separate or identify them using Identifier. After creating custom cell, you can add tableview cell into Cellforrowatindex path method.Make sure don't forgot to import "custom cell.h" in your implementation file. Thanks.